# Transforma string em decimal dentro de um objeto

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, viewmodel

Fiz uma ViewModel, onde no banco o campo CPF é decimal(11,0) e na VM eu coloquei como String. Na minha API o CPF é decimal. Bem, quando eu preencho o campo e envio o form para a API, o valor do CPF chega com 0.0. Isso é esperado, pois eu não parseei. Bem, quando o form é enviado pelo submit, ele manda um objeto json certo? Então, eu não consigo tratar isso. Me falaram para usar AutoMapper, mas acho muita coisa, para apenas parsear/converter um campo. Aqui está minha VM(é necessário essas anotations?)

```
 public class FuncionarioViewModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int id { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Nome do funcionário é obrigatório", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        [Display(Name = "Nome")]
        public String nome { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Data de Nascimento do funcionário é obrigatório", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        [Display(Name = "Data de Nascimento")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage = "formato de data invalido")]
        public DateTime dataNascimento { get; set; }

        //[Required(ErrorMessage = "CPF do funcionário é obrigatório", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        [Display(Name = "CPF")]
        [DataType(DataType.Text, ErrorMessage = "Formato inválido")]
        public String cpf { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Nome da Cidade")]
        public String NomeCidade { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Cidade do funcionário é obrigatório", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        [Display(Name = "Cidade")]
        public virtual int cidade { get; set; }
    }
```

Minha Model é essa na API

```
public class Funcionario
    {
        [Key]
        public int id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public String nome { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public DateTime dataNascimento { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public decimal cpf { get; set; }
        public String NomeCidade { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int cidade { get; set; }
    }
```

Esse método eu disparo a Stored Proc que grava no banco(aqui CPF já está 0.0)

```
public class PostFuncionario
    {
        BancoContext banco = new BancoContext();

        //Método que insere um novo funionario no banco de dados.
        public HttpResponseMessage PostFuncionarios(Funcionario funcionario)
        {
            banco.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("exec sp_ins_funcionarios @nome, " +
                                             "@datanascimento, " +
                                             "@cpf, " +
                                             "@cidade", 
                                             new SqlParameter("@nome", funcionario.nome),
                                             new SqlParameter("@datanascimento", funcionario.dataNascimento),
                                             new SqlParameter("@cpf", funcionario.cpf),
                                             new SqlParameter("@cidade", funcionario.cidade));

            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
    }
```

e aqui é onde eu envio para a API(acho que deveria ser aqui o parse de string para decimal, mas não sei fazer)

```
public async Task PostFuncionarioVM(FuncionarioViewModel funcionario)
        {
            string url = $"http://localhost:56137/api/PostFuncionario";
            var uri = new Uri(string.Format(url));
            var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(funcionario);
            var content = new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            HttpResponseMessage response = null;
            response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);
        }
```

Aqui o cpf está vindo ainda com a máscara, mas na API ele já chega 0.0. Onde eu faço o parse dele?

Comment: Você não pode alterar o tipo do campo? CPF pode conter 0 a esquerda, informação que em um campo numérico será perdida.

Comment: Como o @RobertodeCampos, comentou... você não deveria estar armazenando o cpf como numérico independente de guardar com máscara ou sem. Isso só vai gerar mais trabalho em tratamentos posteriores.

Comment: Eu sei disso, mas não posso alterar o tipo. Tem que ser numérico. Já conversei com o responsável e deverá ser assim, segundo ele me disse, então não quis mais persuadi-lo. Esse é o ponto comigo. Respondendo ao @RobertodeCampos, terei que usar sempre um padleft(11)

Comment: Nunca vi o tipo do campo com decimal '-', @RobertodeCampos tem toda razão.

Comment: Não acredito que fizeram a proeza de usar `decimal` para CPF, eu já vi muita tipagem errada, mas essa foi demais.

Answer (score 2):

Aqui uma solução "limpa" com `Regex`:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public async Task PostFuncionarioVM(FuncionarioViewModel funcionario)
{
    var uri = new Uri("http://localhost:56137/api/PostFuncionario");

    funcionario.cpf = Regex.Replace(funcionario.cpf, "[^0-9]", string.Empty);

    var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(funcionario);
    var content = new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);;
}
```

Vão ser retirados da `string` todos os caracteres não-numéricos, assim não há erro.

Answer (score 1):

Se você está enviando o CPF com a máscara, na hora da conversão ele não identificará como um número, e já que está estruturado desta maneira, remova a máscara antes de enviar para a API.

```
    public async Task PostFuncionarioVM(FuncionarioViewModel funcionario)
    {
        string url = $"http://localhost:56137/api/PostFuncionario";
        var uri = new Uri(string.Format(url));

        funcionario.cpf = funcionario.cpf
        .Replace(".", null)
        .Replace("-", null);

        var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(funcionario);
        var content = new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        HttpResponseMessage response = null;
        response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);
    }
```

Comment: danspark, se faço dessa forma o final dele fica assim:123\345\456 e isso não consigo também gravar.

Comment: Substitua os apóstrofos por áspas e os caracteres '\0' por null

Comment: danspark, assim deu certo. Mas eu criei o cpf no banco como decimal e quando gravo grava assim: 12345678922.0 e não 12345678922. Isso é outro post, certo? Vou marcar sua resposta, mas você precisa editar e colocar conforme seu comentário.